# Using batch to copy one file from another pc to mine using homegroup

Tags: batch-file

My room mate and I have a homegroup set up, but that's all the networking we can do on the university network. Trying to copy one single file from his computer (in my docs folder, which i can access via explorer) to my computer.

```
xcopy /s /v /y "Homegroup\Aaron\DESKTOP-RHML0SE\Documents\Currency.bin" "C:\Users\Grant\AppData\Roaming\AnkhHeart\AnkhBotR2\Twitch\Databases\"
```

That's the code I have, and it doesn't seem to see the file on his drive (Homegroup\Aaron). I just get "File not found - Currency.bin. 0 files copied."

Copying from various places on my own computer works fine. How can i copy from his?

Comment: It may prove beneficial to enter `Net Use /?` at the Command prompt. Also what is the purpose of using the `/S` option to your `XCopy` command.

Comment: This is more a superuser.com question.

Comment: Use `"\\server\share\path\file"` for Universal Naming Convention (UNC) names, where `server`  is the name of the computer (see `net view`) and `share` is the name of the shared folder (listed in `net view \\server`).